# Notation of the set of all the numbers $y$ satisfying an equation $y= ax + b $ with $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: notation

I want to know the notation of a set $\mathcal{S} $ containing all $y $ that satisfy an equation $y = ax + b$ with $x \in  \mathbb{Z}$, for example $2x - 5$ or $\pi x + \frac {5}{2}\pi$.

For instance, given the equation  $y = 2x + 3$ ($x \in \mathbb{Z}$), the set of solutions would be $\mathcal{S} = \{\dots , 1, 3, 5, \dots \} $.

Comment: How about $a\mathbb Z + b$?

Comment: So $\mathcal{S} = a\mathbb{Z} + b$ or $\mathcal{S} = \{ y | y = a\mathbb{Z} + b \}$?

Comment: $a\mathbb Z + b = \{ ax+b \mid x\in \mathbb Z \}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the notation is simple. in general:
$$
\mathcal S = \{\textrm{element} | \textrm{constraints to the element}\}
$$
in this case you could write (most used notation):
$$
\mathcal S = \{ax+b| x \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
or equivalently:
$$
\mathcal S = \{y \in \mathbb R|y=ax+b, x \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
or for the most compactness:
$$
\mathcal S = a \mathbb Z+b
$$

Answer (score 3):

The response $a\mathbb{Z}+b$, given by others, is certainly correct.  It is worth noticing, though, that this designation is not unique:  if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are two numbers that differ only by a multiple of $a$, then $a\mathbb{Z}+b_1$ and $a\mathbb{Z}+b_2$ describe the exact same set.

For this reason, the specific example in the OP could be described by any of the following:

- As $2\mathbb{Z}+3$
- As $2\mathbb{Z}+1$
- As $2\mathbb{Z}-1$
- or indeed as $2\mathbb{Z}+n$ for any odd number $n$.

Comment: true, i'm giving a +1 since this aspect is not covered in my answer